# How do we draw a line with points in three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js

I want to able to create a straight line with new THREE.Points() can someone please tell me how to do it

i tried putting a bunch of particles and assigning each positions with an array and for loop but they had unequal spacing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Example:

```
var geometry = new THREE.Geometry();
var lineMaterial = new THREE.LineBasicMaterial({ color: 0xFF0000, opacity: 0.9 });

geometry.vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3(-AXIS_EXTREME, 0, 0));
geometry.vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3(AXIS_EXTREME, 0, 0));
var xAxis =  new THREE.Line(geometry, lineMaterial);
scene.add(xAxis);
```

This draws a line between two points identified by a Vector3 object. Just add more points to `geometry.vertices` to add more segments.

EDIT:
Following prisoner849's comment, I realized that I may have cut a too dated example. Another way of doing this is:

```
const plusPoint = [];
plusPoint.push(new THREE.Vector3(currentLimit, -this.limit, 0));
plusPoint.push(new THREE.Vector3(currentLimit, this.limit, 0));
const plusGeom = new THREE.BufferGeometry().setFromPoints(plusPoint);
const plusLine = new THREE.Line(plusGeom, this.material);

scene.add(plusLine);
```

This works with v. 0.130.0

Comment: @tcgconsolee Won't work since r125, when `Geometry` was removed from the framework.